# Function awfully slow

Tags: python, performance, parsing, web-scraping, bigdata

I was looking for historical data from our Brazilian stock market and found it at Bovespa's
website.
The problem is the format the data is in is terrible, it is mingled with all sorts of
other information about any particular stock!
So far so good! A great opportunity to test my fresh python skills (or so I thought)!
I managed to "organize/parse" pretty much all of the data with a few lines of code,
and then stumbled on a very annoying fact about the data. The very information I needed, stock prices(open, high, low, close), had no commas and was formatted like this: 0000000011200, which would be equivalent to 11 digits before the decimal comma. 
So basically 0000000011200 = 112,00... You get the gist..

I wrote a few lines of code to edit that and then the nightmare kicked in.
The whole data set is around 358K rows long, and with my current script the deeper it
runs inside the list to edit it the longer it takes per edit.

Here is the code snipped I used for that:

```
@profile
def dataFix(datas):
    x = 0
    for entry in datas:
        for i in range(9, 16):
            data_org[datas.index(entry)][i] = entry[i][:11]+'.'+entry[i][11:]
        x += 1
        print x
```

Would anyone  mind shining  some light into this matter?

Comment: Oh, apologies, x is just a counter variable I used to visualize the progress of each iteration, just to make sure it was infact slowing down.

Comment: what does `data_org[datas.index(entry)][i]` do?

Comment: It references the position in my data_org list which I want to alter. Each item in the data_org list is a list with information regarding a particular stock. With that in mind I would like to change positions 9 through to 15 of each item in data_org. So for the first member of data_org I want to change data_org[1][9] --- data_org[1][15] each one corresponding to a price. Also datas is identical to data_org.

Comment: little grammar nip here: data is already plural. Data is the plural of datum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
datas.index(entry)
```

There's your problem. `datas.index(entry)` requires Python to go through the `datas` list one element at a time, searching for `entry`. It's an incredibly slow way to do things, slower the bigger the list is, and it doesn't even work, because duplicate elements are always found at their first occurrence instead of the occurrence you're processing.

If you want to use the indices of the elements in a loop, use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for index, entry in enumerate(datas):
    ...
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a bunch man the code runs very fast now. When you are a noobie it's easy to forget these primordial functions in python which just make your life tons easier.

Answer (score 1):

First, probably more easy to convert price directly to a more usable format.
For exemple Decimal format permit you to do easy calculation without loosing precision.
Secondly, i think you didn't even need the index and can just use append.
Thirdly, say welcome to list comprehension and slice :P

```
from decimal import Decimal

data_org = []
for entries in datas:
    data_org.append([Decimal(entry).scaleb(-2) for entry in entries[9:16]])
```

or even:

```
data_org = [[Decimal(entry).scaleb(-2) for entry in entries[9:16]] for entries in datas]
```

or in a generator form:

```
data_org = ([Decimal(entry).scaleb(-2) for entry in entries[9:16]] for entries in datas)
```

or if you want to keeping the text form:

```
data_org = [['.'.join((entry[:-2], entry[-2:])) for entry in entries[9:16]] for entries in datas]
```

(replaceing [:11] by [:-2] permit to be independent of the input size and get 2 decimal from the end)

Comment: Brilliant! That is some sophisticated code, for me at least, but I did understand how list comprehension can smooth things out. One thing to point out however.. I did run your snippet but my interpreter spat out an error.

Comment: InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal: 'OPEN.'

Comment: Sorry, please dis-consider my last comment, I was stupid enough not to take into account the fact that the first item of data_org was a list containing column titles for db purposes.

Comment: Although now that I can run the code, I ran the version with the list comprehension and it's taking very long. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: oups, didn't think of that... division on Decimal are really slow. Change by using scaleb method. Should be better